# How can I do this: Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I receive this message when I run *rake db:migrate*

```
macpro:rp-blogRails jpcpamies$ rake db:migrate
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from setup at /Users/jpcpamies/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/stylus-1.0.1/lib/stylus/sprockets.rb:42)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the a deprecated processor interface Stylus::ImportProcessor.
Please update your processor interface:
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from setup at /Users/jpcpamies/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/stylus-1.0.1/lib/stylus/sprockets.rb:43)
```

I get that I need to register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.

OK! How do I do that??

PS: I have done already

```
bundle update
```

And I am running already

```
Using sass 3.4.22
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
```

Answer (score 3):

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
>
> Please register a mime type using register_mime_type then use  register_compressor or register_transformer.

It is a `sprockets` issue, the quick fix is

```
gem 'sprockets', '3.6.3'
```

but existing one will work on the production env.